# Gradle Multi-Project Build and Encapsulation

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradle as build engine for multiple projects. I have the following dependency between the projects:

```
- MobileApp
|
+-- CordovaPlugin
   |
   +--Docs
   |
   +--NativeiOSImpl
   |  |
   |  +--Docs
   +--NativeAndroidImpl
      |
      +--Docs
```

Each of the projects is a project on it own so each project has it own build.gradle file and settings.gradle.

My problem is that I have to repeat the settings.gradle in each level.
Am I missing something or there is no encapulation of a project in gradle?

Comment: You can put a single settings.gradle file at the root of the hierarchy that defines all the projects.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I wish my for project will not have to know the internal dependencies of the Cordova plugin project

Comment: Gradle doesn't support hierarchical builds like you want (having multiple settings.gradle's). Every project is isolated from each other including child projects.